# HTTPRequest ajax error with slesh in end of Uri in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, uri

Help guest...
i make web using framework Codeigniter and also using ajax XMLHttp Request to load some data from DB.

**if i open the link Like this**

```
  localhost/web/topsales
```

**every things is OK like this.** [Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zX5v.png)

but if i add slash in end of url

```
localhost/web/topsales/
```

the result is error. Ajax load and duplicate the pages view like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9hKn.png)

i use AJAX XMLHttp Request for load the data:

```
function showdata()
{
    var idunit = document.getElementById('idunit').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('month').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
    var xmlhttp;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<div class='text-center'>Loading...</div>"; //xmlhttp.responseText
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; //xmlhttp.responseText
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","showresult",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("idunit="+idunit+"&month="+month+"&year="+year);
}
```

please i need help, thanks so much for some advice.

Comment: You might have to configure the routes to handle both. I think CodeIgniter is seeing the extra / as a new route. Also, I am amazed to see IE5 and IE6 support. We don't even support IE9 anymore.

Comment: I had cofigure the routes and also .htaccess.. but no one is working. It still load the main page view like above... not data from db like i want.